# Variables are global with SASS but not SCSS

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, sass, sass-rails

I have my `application.css.scss` set like this:

```
@import "base/variables";
@import "./application/application";
```

[Like the documentation says](https://github.com/rails/sass-rails#important-note) I am not using Sprockets' directives (`require`, `require_tree`, and `require_self`) at all so I expect my variables defined inside of `base/_variables.scss` to be globals and available for my `/application/application.scss` file but it's not the case:

```
#content {
  margin-top: $big;
}
```

Will return the error `Undefined variable: "$big"`.

I've tried the same thing with SASS by naming by files `application.css.sass` and `/application/application.sass` and while the variables now do seems to be globals I'll like to keep using the SCSS syntax, I've tried that by setting `config.sass.preferred_syntax = :scss` but I'm still being asked for Sass.

Of course I could just import my variables file everytime I need my variables but that would go against the DRY principle.

Is that possible to use the SCSS syntax while making my variables globally available? What am I missing here? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My `application/application.scss` was being precompiled (in `assets.rb`) by an old rule using a wildcard, which I missed, it's now working correctly.

Answer (score 0):

What versions of `sprockets`, `rails` and `sass-rails` gems do you have? There were [some problems](https://github.com/rails/sass-rails/issues/379) around undefined variables, maybe try to bump up `sass-rails` and `sprockets` (if possible).

Comment: `sprockets 3.7.1`, `rails 4.2.5` and `sass-rails 5.0.6`